# Is taking a reference from a temporary valid C++ code?

Tags: c++, reference, c++17, temporary-objects

I used the following syntactic sugar:

```
for (auto& numberString: {"one", "two", "three", "four"}) { /* ... */}
```

Is this valid code? AFAIK, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301179/why-is-taking-the-address-of-a-temporary-illegal), this should be illegal, yet the code runs as expected. I don't think my understanding is correct on the matter.

As far as I know, only literals should not have memory addresses, yet the linked question is talking about temporaries and [r-values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#lrvalue).

Comment: The temporary `std::initializer_list` object will actually have a life-time that encompasses the loop, so it's valid.

Comment: So if my understanding is correct: as long as the lifetime of a temporary is valid, taking a reference from it is valid behavior. In the referenced question, there is no connection to String literals, only the lifetime of the temporary is relevant. Am I understaning it correctly?

Comment: Yes it's the lifetime of the temporary that matters. As long as the lifetime of the temporary is longer than the lifetime of the reference, all is good and well.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, this code is valid.

Keep in mind that (for C++17), the compiler will semantically replace the range-based for loop by the construct

```cpp
{

    auto && __range = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
    for (auto __begin = begin(__range), __end = end(__range); __begin != __end; ++__begin)
    {

        auto& numberString = *__begin;
        /* ... */
    }

}
```

You see, the lifetime of the `initializer_list` is extended to the lifetime of `__range` inside of the outermost scope in the replacement.

Note however that you still can easily cause undefined behavior if the range expression contains a temporary itself:

```cpp
struct some {
   auto get_list() { return {"one", "two", "three", "four"}; }
};

some foo() { return some{ }; }

for(auto& numberString : foo().get_list()) { /* ... */ }
```

The above code will result in a dangling reference in <= C++20.
Only in C++23, the lifetime of the temporary created by `foo()` will get extended such that it becomes valid. See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: I'm pretty sure your second example would only be undefined if `get_list` returned a reference to a member of `some`.  As-is, `foo` returns a temporary `some` object which lives until the end of the full expression, which is long enough to call `get_list` on it.  `get_list` returns a temporary object which then gets lifetime-extended per the usual rules.

Comment: Actually I think the second example is undefined even in C++20. The backing buffer of the initializer_list is local to `get_list`, and no lifetime extension of the initializer_list return value will change that. (GCC and Clang both warn about returning the address of a temporary once I change the return type to `std::initializer_list<const char*>`)