# Bind an lvalue reference to an rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, reference, forward, lvalue, rvalue

I have tried to compile:

```
int &&a=3;
int &b=a;
```

And it work.
I know that "a" is an lvalue, but why i can bind an "rvalue reference to int" to an "lvalue reference to int (not to an rvalue reference to int)"?
This way, i can change the value of the temporary, 3:

```
b=5 //changing the value of the temporary bound to the rvalue reference
```

This tecnique is used from std::forward, so i suppose it is a standard behavior.
Is an rvalue reference to int considered as a simple int lvalue storing a temporary?
If not, how do you explain the binding?

Answer (score 6):

**References don't bind to other references; they bind to objects.**

When you initialise `a` from `3`, you create a new, temporary `int` object [whose lifetime is extended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205082/560648). `b` is simply another reference to that object.

Note that `a` *is* an lvalue, because it is an expression naming an object, even though it has *type* "rvalue-reference to `int`"! Be careful not to confuse *types* with *value categories*, here: types relate to objects, but value categories relate to *expressions* (even if those expressions name or otherwise evaluate to some object).

These confusing rules all fit in together quite neatly when you think about it: for the original reference to have been valid, the object's lifetime must have been extended, so `b`'s initialisation is safe.

Comment: But, i know that only const lvalue reference can be bound to a temporary. Is there any rule that let a plain lvalue reference to be bound to a temporary, if its lifetime is extended?

Comment: @Toccio: That's not true. Only const lvalue references (and rvalue references) may be bound to an object accessed through an rvalue expression. But `a` is an lvalue expression because it refers to an object's _name_. It doesn't really matter than the object the references refer to is a temporary.

Comment: One more questions: when i bind lvalue reference A to an other lvalue reference B that refer to C, what i'm really doing is binding A to C right? So, if B is an rvalue reference, and C is a temporary, is it like i bind A to C?

Comment: @Toccio: Ehm I guess so; your question isn't too clear.

Comment: Mh, try this way: an int& can be bound to an int lvalue, to int& and to int&& that are lvalue (like the example in the first post). Change the value of an int& is like change the value of the object referenced by it.Calling this object O, if O is, in turn, a reference (rvalue or lvalue doesn't matter), the change to O will, in turn, be a change on the object referenced by O, and so on, until a reach a non-reference type.
Is all of this right?

Comment: You're still confused. You can't "change the value of an int&", and you can't bind a "int&" to an "int&" or a "int&&". You _are_ operating on, or binding to, "the object referenced by it". In a parallel universe you're correct because the end result is the same, but in our universe there is no "chaining" because there doesn't need to be!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60765/discussion-between-toccio-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).